# Why does the XCode 4 GM console show processes in decimal and threads in hexadecimal?

Tags: macos, unix, xcode4

Purely out of curiosity:

I'm doing some UNIX dev in XCode 4 GM and I noticed in the console output that process ID's are being displayed in decimal while thread ID's are being displayed in hexadecimal.

Example:

```
[Switching to process 37574 thread 0x0]
```

Why are these conventions used ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because process ids are usually displayed in decimal (Activity Monitor, top, ps, etc.), and thread ids are usually hexadecimal (gdb, various other debugging tools). I suspect the reason for that is, ultimately, so they're easier to tell apart. (Just remember "2378,0xF4" and you don't need to remember which is the pid or the tid.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  That's an interesting point; had not considered that for sake of human memory.